# Having problems with setting up server behind NAT

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, centos, nat

My OS: CentOS 7

Server: Apache

Equipment: Sterlite SAM 300AX

Okay so I'm trying to set up my server on my home connection, and been having some problems. I have been allotted a static WAN IP by my ISP. I have two computers, one is the server and other is a home PC behind a modem-cum-router.

Currently when I go to my WAN IP (either myself or from a public proxy) I land on my modem login page.

I wonder if its a problem with ports or something. Or is it the host/hosts/httpd.conf setting on my apache or mix of other things. Perhaps its the firewall issue?

My /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.13 server.mysite.com
```

My httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin localhost@root
ServerName server.mysite.com

</Default Stuff>

IncludeOptional conf.d/* .conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/* .conf
```

My vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.13:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/requests.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In my Router, under NAT I added the following:

```
1   HTTP_Server     TCP     80  80  192.168.1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very bad and insecure.  If the router is presenting you the login details from the WAN, that is almost certainly your problem.   I can't find a manual for this device, but you should either turn off this functionality or replace the device (or upgrade firmeware and see if that fixes it...)

This is also important because as the web server is bound to the external IP address and port of the device it won't let you forward that port to your device - thus no settings you make on your computer will help - the traffic is not getting there.   You can test this theory by using an alternative port on the router and forwarding it to port 80 on your device (and then accessing it as http://ip.addr:portno

Comment: Two links, giving details of Device software:

http://mtnldelhi.in/broadband/triband_modem.htm (SAM 300ax)

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Sterlite/SAM300-AX/Apache.htm

Comment: [ Please ensure you can reset the router/go to factor if it locks up - this is an educated gess ] - Looking at one of the pages for the router if you go to Access Management, Under Acces Control it looks like you can change the Interface - I'm guessing its set as "Both".  Change that to the lan interface only [ don't know what its called in software as I'm going from a screenshot ]

Comment: If you go to the first link and download the driver, the entire manual for this modem is available inside the rar file there. with all the pages. Perhaps that will help you to figure out someway ?